# form - output empty checkboxes (array) in a foreach loop (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I got a problem & don't get the solutions, hope you can help me!

I created a form which have visitors with optional a guest.
The sense of the form is to delete the visitor and the guest.
Now you got some options:

1. Delete the visitor and the guest
2. Delete only the visitor
3. Delete only the guest

Here are my checkboxes in a while-loop:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_loeschen)) 
{
echo "<td class='disable'><input type='text' name='AnmeldungID[]' value=".$row[ID]."></td>";    
echo "<input type='hidden' name='option[0]' value='0' />";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='option[0]' value='1' /></td> ";

echo "<input type='hidden' name='option[1]' value='0' />";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='option[1]' value='2' /></td> ";

echo "<input type='hidden' name='option[2]' value='0' />";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='option[2]' value='3' /></td> ";
}
```

After the form is send:

```
foreach($_POST['AnmeldungID'] as $key => $ID) { 
    $option = $_POST['option'][$key];

    echo $ID;
    echo " = ";
    echo $option;
    echo "<br />";
    }
```

But it does not work, if all are checked - the output is:

> 19 = 1
>   12 = 0
>   14 = 0
>   15 = 0

Any ideas?
Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the name to `option[]` in every checkbox.

Maybe radiobuttons are the better choice for your goal?

Comment: I got an if-statement:

    if (!empty($row[guest_name])) {
  echo "<input type='hidden' name='option[]' value='0' />";
  echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='option[]' value='1' /></td> ";
  echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='option[]' value='2' /></td> ";
  echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='option[]' value='3' /></td> ";
  }
    else{
  echo "<input type='hidden' name='option[]' value='0' />";
  echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='option[]' value='4' /></td> ";
  }

Comment: I checked following:

    ID 19 = 1
    ID 18 = 4 //without a guest
    ID 12 = 4 //without a guest
    ID 16 = 4 //without a guest


Output is following:

    ID 19 = 1
    ID 18 = 0 //without a guest
    ID 12 = 4 //without a guest
    ID 16 = 0 //without a guest


And radiobuttons are not the better choice, because the while loop. 
Got more than one entry.

Comment: Why you got the input type="hidden"? If you don't check a checkbox, it will get no value, so the type="hidden" field is not necessary and will cause problems with the same name option[].

Comment: I need a value for each entry, without the type="hidden" i got some empty values and the entry will be skip and the ID's are uncorrect

Comment: OK then you're right to give fixed values to your checkboxes as above. Did you make 3*3 checkboxes in your test above?

Comment: Which one is correct? name='option[1]' value='1' or name='option[]' value='1'

Comment: Well when you set the name to option[1] only the last checkbox of the last while loop will get option[1]. All other checkboxes with this names which are printed out before will lost their values.

Comment: The main problem is, the type="hidden" field is showing even if the checkbox is checked.

Comment: That is browser depending. You should not use the hidden field with the same name but rather the if(isset(.. method in my comment above.

Comment: And where I need to put the if(isset? if(isset($option)){
     echo $ID;
     echo " = ";
     echo $option;
     echo "<br />";
     }

Comment: Well you can try foreach(..) { if(isset($_POST['option'][$key]) $option = $_POST['option'][$key]; else $option = 0; echo $ID;.....}

Comment: Hmmm.. I got an idea.. need to check if all checkboxes are checked or not.. if not I need to make a 'break'

Comment: Hmmmm.. i don't get it... if(isset($_POST['option'][$key])){
  $option = $_POST['option'][$key];
  }
  else{
  break;
  }

Comment: The you will break the whole foreach. Do you only want to jump to the next loop you must use continue;

Comment: no I want to break the whole foreach - but it didn't work with the pasted code.

Comment: Well, this should work - maybe you can change isset($_POST['option'][$key]) to !empty($_POST['option'][$key]) which will check if it's empty or 0.

Comment: It doesn't... my final solution are select-menus now ;) Thanks 4 your help!